# I'm new to coding, and I'm not too sure why my index.html won't load properly.

Tags: html, css

```
html {
  background : url(../images/20141105_183642.jpg) left top no-repeat fixed;
  background-size : cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background:url (../images/20141105_183642.jpg) #000000 no-repeat left top;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

The text and links are all right so far, so I will only include the background CSS section. Before I moved my html and css into organised folders (and the above is just a part of my University assignment, in which I'm having trouble with.) Could I receive some enlightenment for where I went wrong? As my Index page is not fully loading, and I'm starting to pull my hair out on this one. Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `<style type="text/css">` between `html { ... }` and `body { ... }`?

Comment: Also, could you add your index.html and explain better what do you mean with "fully loading"? The page is not rendered as you expect? In which way?

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules must be enclosed in the `<style>` tag (*which should be closed with a `</style>`*) if they are not in external files..

```
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
      background : url(../images/20141105_183642.jpg) left top no-repeat fixed;
      background-size : cover;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    body {
        background:url (../images/20141105_183642.jpg) #000000 no-repeat left top;
        background-size: 100%;
    } 
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `<style type="text/css">` from your snippet; you say you moved your css and html into organised folders, I assume you moved it into a .css file?

If so, you can import it, assuming it's in the same directory, into your .html file with:
`<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

You should place that line in between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags in your html document.